How can I get PM2 to load a new cron_restart?
I have a PM2 server running an ecosystem config file with certain jobs using the cron_restart functionality. I had one job configured as 0 6 * * * (every day at 6:00) and changed it to 0 10 * * * (every day at 10:00). I then restarted the ecosystem like this:
pm2 startOrReload ecosystem.config.js --update-env

The job still fired at 6:00 every day. So I tried this:
pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js

Still 6:00.
How do I have to restart PM2 to get it to refresh/reload the new cron_restart?

The --update-env flag notify pm2 to refresh ENV vars, so if you just update your ecosystem file, this flag just do nothing.
To change your cron value first issue a pm2 list command and identify the task number you want to update.
Then issue this command: pm2 restart 0 --cron-restart="0 10 * * *". In this example i assume you process ID is "0".
Also update your ecosystem file and don't forget to issue a pm2 save command to save your configuration.

Yep, this works. I also found that if I deleted the job with pm2 delete and restarted the ecosystem (pm2 restart ecosystem.config.js) after changing the cron_restart value in the ecosystem file, that worked as well but was a bit more brute-force.

happy to have been able to help you
